# $F(x,y)=f(x)g(y)$, $F(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)=h(\theta)$, find $F(x,y)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, chain-rule

My progress:
$$F_x(x,y)=f'(x)g(y)$$  $$F_y(x,y)=f(x)g'(y)$$ also, $$F(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)=h(\theta)$$
taking partial derivative with respect to $r$ and using chain rule:
$$F_x(x,y)\cos\theta+F_y(x,y)\sin\theta=0$$
$$F_x(x,y)r\cos\theta+F_y(x,y)r\sin\theta=0$$
$$F_x(x,y)x+F_y(x,y)y=0$$
$$f'(x)g(y)x+f(x)g'(y)y=0$$
And......I got stuck. if only the positive sign were negative.....then that would be easy. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Exclude the origin from the domain of $f$, as $\theta$ is not defined there.

Comment: I'm sorry, why isn't it defined there?

Comment: Because the polar angle is only defined  in the punctured plane. Apart from that, including the origin trivializes the problem, as one of the answers shows.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I  am missing something but this looks trivial. Put $r=0$ to see that $h(\theta)=F(0,0)$. So $h$ is constant and this means $F$ is a constant.

Answer (score 1):

Write your last equation in the form
${x f'(x)\over f(x)}+{y\, g'(y)\over g(y)}=0$. This implies that
$$-{x f'(x)\over f(x)}={y\, g'(y)\over g(y)}=\lambda$$
for some real (or complex) constant $\lambda$. The ODE
$$g'(y)={\lambda\over y}g(y)$$
has the solutions
$$g(y)=C' y^\lambda\qquad(y>0)\ ,$$
and similarly you obtain
$$f(x)=C'' x^{-\lambda}\qquad(x>0)\ .$$
It follows that in the first quadrant $I:=\bigl\{(x,y)\bigm|x>0, \ y>0\bigr\}$
you have $$F(x,y)=C\left({y\over x}\right)^\lambda\qquad\bigl((x,y)\in I\bigr)\ .$$
This $F$ is obviously constant on rays emanating from the origin.

One can  also produce an $F$ with a larger domain. E.g., when $\lambda>0$ you can put $$F(x,y):=\left|{y\over x}\right|^\lambda\ .$$
This is defined on all of ${\mathbb R}^2\setminus\{y$-axis$\}$.